# When i get data with Axios my JS code doesn't works

Tags: vue.js, axios

Hello I'm newbie at `Vue` and `axios`.I have a pure js in my codes and i'm changing the class of the list `items(class="current")` and switching between the tabs and everything is fine.

When I pre-define my categories array like:

```
categories:["Title 1","Title 2","Title 3"]
```

Listing list elements:

```
<li v-for="(category,index) in categories"><a :href="'#'+index"><span>0{{index+1}}</span>{{category}} </a></li>
```

This works well. I can change the class and switch between tabs.

But when I get the categories from the database, javascript doesn't works and i can't see it in the console.

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        categories:[],
    },
    mounted(){
     axios
     .get('getCategories.php')
     .then(response => {
        this.categories = response.data;
    })
 }});
```

[Image1:Predefined Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSwwx.png)

[Image2:Generated categories with axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdFjD.png)

Comment: Looks like a reactivity problem. You might push every returning element from `response.data` into your `categories` array. This should fix the issue.

Comment: Do you have `axios.defaults.baseURL` set?

Comment: @Aer0 i tried this.response.data.forEach(item=>{this.categories.push(item)}) and nothing changed.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights added now but no changes

Comment: Try including the localhost URL directly in the request: `http://localhost:8000/getCategories.php`. Replace `8000` with whatever port your server's running on

Comment: @Daniel_Knights still same :/

Comment: On Image2 you inpect the generated DOM, and the data is there.

Comment: Could you post your PHP code?

Comment: tbh, you should at least tell us what result found via `console.log(response.data);` As we don't see the problem whether lies at your server .php side or client side

Comment: @Aer0 is partially right, I've already encountered this problem: vue do not re-render the page if an array has changed (don't know why), you have to bind some other variable (like a boolean) to a view element and change its value when axios request is completed so it can trigger a page re-render

Comment: Actually vue can re-render the list elements if the array changes

Comment: @Ifaruki I know it should, but I had the same problem of re-render not triggered cause of array changes not detected by vue... I repeat: don't understand why there is this behaviour

Comment: In case anyone is interested. Vue is able to track changes within Arrays but only for each individual index. That said, exchanging the whole array doesn't work, whereas updating a specific index triggers a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

You should always put an unique `key` if you use a `v-for` loop

```
  <li v-for="(category,index) in categories" :key="index">
```

I used here index as unique key but you should use something else thats unique, maybe the category name

Comment: Added :key="category" but no changes.

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: That won't work either. The `:key` itself only tells Vue wich node it should re-render performance wise. So working without `:key` is possible, but it's not considered best practice since it'll trigger a whole re-render for that block and not only for each individually changed node.

Answer (score 0):

Vue's reactivity system works pretty good in overall. However, there's always some pitfalls in every language and framework. Same goes for Vue, obviously. In your specific case Vue just can't update the array properly which is why your view doesn't re-render. You can read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays). But there's always hope. Let's talk a bit about `[Vue.$set][1]`. In cases where the automatic reactivity system just fails to work or just doesn't work as expected, you can always use `Vue.$set` manually. In fact, Vue just uses this function internally for all of your variables which are initially set in your `data`.

So in your case this should actually solve your issue.

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        categories:[],
    },
    mounted(){
     axios
     .get('getCategories.php')
     .then(response => {
         response.data.forEach((d, i) => {
             this.$set(this.categories, i, d);
         }
    })
 }});
```